# Workaround to using widgets in Colab

Tags: python, widget, jupyter, google-colaboratory, fast-ai

I’m trying to use the widgets from `fastai.widgets import *` in Colab but as some users have pointed out, colab does not permit the use of widgets. A user suggested setting up a local Jupyter environment, connecting it to Drive and running the widget. My question is: How can I do this? I’ve never used widgets before, let alone running them on a different platform. Could someone guide me?